# Attribute selection in matlab using WEKA

Tags: matlab, weka, feature-selection

I do the major of my signal processing tasks in matlab, but i need an algorithm from weka. And all the time I have to migrate from one to the other. I was wondering if I could run the SVMAttributeEval algorithm from Weka inside matlab. I found some usufull posts for trainning and evaluating classifiers from weka inside matlab, but none of them applies correctly to feature selection and i can't get it right.

What I do in Weka is load some CVS database and then in select attributes run a SVMAttributeEval with ranker search method. No cross validation is needed.
Here is my log from weka GUI. It is a really simple operation.

```
12:04:23: Started weka.attributeSelection.SVMAttributeEval
12:04:23: Command: weka.attributeSelection.SVMAttributeEval -s "weka.attributeSelection.Ranker -T -1.7976931348623157E308 -N -1" -X 1 -Y 0 -Z 0 -P 1.0E-25 -T 1.0E-10 -C 1.0 -N 0
12:04:23: Filter command:  weka.filters.supervised.attribute.AttributeSelection -E "weka.attributeSelection.SVMAttributeEval -X 1 -Y 0 -Z 0 -P 1.0E-25 -T 1.0E-10 -C 1.0 -N 0" -S "weka.attributeSelection.Ranker -T -1.7976931348623157E308 -N -1"
12:04:23: Meta-classifier command: weka.classifiers.meta.AttributeSelectedClassifier -E "weka.attributeSelection.SVMAttributeEval -X 1 -Y 0 -Z 0 -P 1.0E-25 -T 1.0E-10 -C 1.0 -N 0" -S "weka.attributeSelection.Ranker -T -1.7976931348623157E308 -N -1" -W weka.classifiers.trees.J48 -- -C 0.25 -M 2
12:04:36: Finished weka.attributeSelection.SVMAttributeEval weka.attributeSelection.Ranker
```

What I had done in matlab till now is:

```
%include jar libraries to matlab environment
javaaddpath('C:/Program Files/Weka-3-6/weka.jar');

%imports java like
import weka.classifiers.*;
import weka.classifiers.Classifier.*;
import weka.classifiers.bayes.BayesNet.*;
import weka.classifiers.Evaluation.*;
import weka.attributeSelection.*

filename = java.lang.String('D:/Google Drive Pessoal/Simulação/31_01/processedDirectDriven/DB_fsc.csv');

c = weka.attributeSelection.SVMAttributeEval();
```

But I don't know how to go on. Many of the methods and calls from other posts are for classifiers and not for attribute selectors.
Could please some one help me!?

Thanks,

Luisa.